# Function sequence and some properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

Consider functions $f_n$, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ and every $f_n$ has property $W$. Determine whether $f$ must have $W$ property as well when:

- a)$W$ = continuity
- b)$W$ = differentiability
- c)$W$ = concavity
- d)$W$ = even/odd
- e)$W$ = strict monotonicity

For a) answer is of course yes. How about other ones?

Comment: What are your thought on the subject? What about the point b)? The uniform convergence is a property that only relies on the $f_n$, do you think that without any information on the convergence of $\{{f_n}'\}$, we can say something on the differentiability of $f$?

Comment: I think c),d),e) are not even tricky, you probably will find answer quite easily. For b) try to think of some smooth functions that converge to $|x|$ uniformly